# How do I enable/disable Laravel's route filters for Behat scenarios? [Laravel 5]

Tags: laravel, behat

By default Laravel disables route filters in testing environment and I wasn't able to switch them back on. So I decided to run Behat in another envrionment ('testing-behat').

Now the filters are always enabled. Which is quite annoying as well... ;-)

I would like to enable or disable Laravel's route filters for some scenarios in Behat.

Right now I scattered Route::disableFilters() around pretty much everywhere in my FeatureContext (@beforeSuite, @beforeScenario, @Given).
But to no avail.

So any hint would be appreciated...